# Parsing XML to typed values: xsd2scala?

Tags: xml, scala, haskell, xsd

I have an XSD that gives me the structure of some xml-flavour.

Are there tools that generate scala-types from the XSD and allow me to parse valid XML to values of that type ? Something similar to DtdToHaskell, if you know that one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself: http://scalaxb.org/